# И снова о прусаках

Tags: этикет

Тут, как выяснилось, уже не раз обсуждалось слово "прусак" по отношению к тараканам. Но меня интересует название народа.
А именно: как корректно назвать жителя Пруссии? Прусак или пруссак - звучит как ругательство (именно по аналогии с тараканом). Или все-таки пруссак?
А еще можно ли это считать национальностью? А, если нет (по-моему, жители Пруссии - это все-таки немцы), то что это?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы понимаете под "национальностью". Жителей Австрии некоторые "империалисты" тоже немцами считают, на минуточку. В Германии в силу того, что она объединилась не так давно, сильна региональная идентичность (пруссаки, баварцы, швабы и так далее), но в целом они, насколько я знаю, не противопоставляют её идентичности государственной, "национальной".

Comment: @Пересвет.Насколько я знаю , если австрийца назвать немцем - он обидится или , по крайней мере , поправит .

Comment: @следопыт, отношение самих австрийцев к этому — второй вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исторические жители Пруссии, давшие название сначала области, а потом и государству (ныне исчезнувшему) - **пруссы**.

Это народ балтийской группы, сосем не немцы, ближе даже к славянам. Сейчас и язык, и сама национальность давно исчезли, хотя в этимологических исследованиях прусский язык играет очень важную роль как переходный от германских к остальным балтийским.
Собственно "пруссаками" жители Пруссии стали уже после её онемечивания. И да, это название несет себе несколько презрительную историческую коннотацию. 
Поэтому современных жителей регионов, некогда принадлежащих исторической Пруссии (ныне - в составе разных государств и земель ФРГ) более политкорректно будет так и именовать "жителями Пруссии". Хотя не могу себе представить, чтобы это кому-то понадобилось. После Веймарской Республики (где Пруссия была самой крупной и влиятельной федеральной землей) причин для такого вычленения просто не осталось.

Answer (score 2):

1. Последнее территоральное образование с названием Пруссия исчезло в 1945
    году, а государство с этим именем еще раньше, в 1918. Сейчас 
   историческая область "Пруссия" разделена между Россией (Калининградская 
   область) и Польшей (Поморское воеводство). Жителей этих краев, по 
   национальности, в основном, русские и поляки, еще можно назвать 
   "калининградцами" и "гданьцы", "поморцами" соответственно.
2. Что касается немцев, то исторически в этой области жил народ 
   **пруссы**, однако, в XIII веке на этой территории высадились крестоносцы (тевтонцы), которые распространяли христианство в Восточной 
   Европе. Автохтонное население со временем онемечилось и объединение 
   Германии проходило под знаменами прусских королей, а жителей государства стали называть **пруссаками**. Если верить Википедии, сейчас, себя потомками *пруссов* называют около миллиона жителей Германии, а вот самому молодому *пруссаку* сейчас за 70 лет и думаю ему уже все равно как его называют по-русски.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: пруссак, пруссачка.  ПРУССАКИ́, -о́в, ед. -а́к, -а́, м. Немцы Ч уроженцы или жители бывшей немецкой провинции Пруссии.См. Толковый словарь Ожегова.
Пруссачка; Пруссаки -     Уроженцы или жители Пруссии; северо-восточные немцы. Т***олковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.***